# Understanding CUDA kernel stack usage and register spilling

Tags: cuda

I am trying to fully understand the information of `PTXAS -v` CUDA for kernel stack usage and register spilling (for sm_35 architecture). For one of my kernels it produces:

```
    3536 bytes stack frame, 3612 bytes spill stores, 6148 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 255 registers, 392 bytes cmem[0]
```

I know that the stack frame is allocated in local memory which lives physically where global memory is and is private to each thread.

My questions are:

1. Is the memory needed for register spillage also allocated in local
   memory?
2. Is the total amount of memory needed for register spilling and stack
   usage equal to [number of threads]x[3536 bytes]. Thus register
   spillage loads/stores operate on the stack frame?
3. The number of spill stores/loads doesn't detail on the size of the
   transfers. Are these always 32bit registers? Thus, a 64bit floating
   point number spill would be counted as 2 spill stores?
4. Are spill stores/loads cached in L2 cache?

Comment: May be partially answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388207/interpreting-output-of-ptxas-options-v

Comment: I read the thread. It's partially answered. But this does not justify to close this question. See comment below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Registers are spilled to local memory. "local" means "thread-local", i.e. storage private to each thread.
2. The amount of local memory required for the entire launch is **at least** number_of_threads times local_memory_bytes_per_thread. Due to allocation granularity it can often be more.
3. The compiler statistics for spill transfers *are already normalized
   to bytes* as individual local memory accesses may have difference
   widths. Inspection of the generated machine code (run `cuobjdump
   --dump-sass` on the binary) will show the width of the individual accesses. The relevant instructions will have names like LLD, LST,
   LDL, STL.
4. I am reasonably sure that local memory accesses are cached in L1 and
   L2 caches, but cannot quote the relevant paragraphs from the
   documentation at this time.

Comment: Please answer whether register spill space is included in the stack frame reported or goes on top of it (question 2). I will then be happy to accept your answer.