# Interpreting the verbose output of ptxas, part II

Tags: cuda, verbose, gpu-shared-memory, gpu-constant-memory, ptxas

This question is a continuation of [Interpreting the verbose output of ptxas, part I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388207/) .

When we compile a kernel `.ptx` file with `ptxas -v`, or compile it from a `.cu` file with `-ptxas-options=-v`, we get a few lines of output such as:

```
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'searchkernel(octree, int*, double, int, double*, double*, double*)' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for searchkernel(octree, int*, double, int, double*, double*, double*)
    72 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 46 registers, 176 bytes cmem[0], 16 bytes cmem[14]
```

(same example as in the linked-to question; but with name demangling)

This question regards the last line. A few more examples from other kernels:

```
ptxas info    : Used 19 registers, 336 bytes cmem[0], 4 bytes cmem[2]
...
ptxas info    : Used 19 registers, 336 bytes cmem[0]
... 
ptxas info    : Used 6 registers, 16 bytes smem, 328 bytes cmem[0]
```

How do we interpret the information on this line, other than the number of registers used? Specifically:

- Is `cmem` short for constant memory?
- Why are there different categories of `cmem`, i.e. `cmem[0]`, `cmem[2]`, `cmem[14]`?
- `smem` probably stands for `shared memory`; is it only *static* shared memory?
- Under which conditions does each kind of entry appear on this line?

Comment: Yes, `cmem` refers to constant memory.  The different "categories" (**banks**) are outlined [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#constant-state-space).  I don't see `smem` appearing anywhere in in this question or in the linked question, but it could not possibly refer to *dynamic* shared memory as that is not known (size-wise) at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

> Is cmem short for constant memory?

Yes

> Why are there different categories of cmem, i.e. cmem[0], cmem[2], cmem[14]?

They represent different constant memory banks. `cmem[0]` is the reserved bank for kernel arguments and statically sized constant values.

> smem probably stands for shared memory; is it only static shared memory?

It is, and how could it be otherwise.

> Under which conditions does each kind of entry appear on this line?

Mostly answered [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#printing-code-generation-statistics).

Comment: +1 for the information, but I feel the answer is laid out in an overly conversational manner, so I let myself write one too.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Collected and reformatted...</sub>

Resources on the last ptxas info line:

- **`registers`** - in the register file on every SM (multiprocessor)
- **`gmem`** - Global memory
- **`smem`** - Static Shared memory
- **`cmem[N]`** - Constant memory bank with index N.

  - **`cmem[0]`** - Bank reserved for kernel argument and statically-sized constant values
  - **`cmem[2]`** - ???
  - **`cmem[4]`** - ???
  - **`cmem[14]`** - ???

Each of these categories will be shown if the kernel uses any such memory (Registers - probably always shown); thus it is no surprise all the examples show some `cmem[0]` usage.

You can read a bit more on the CUDA memory hierarchy in [Section 2.3 of the Programming Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-hierarchy) and the links there. Also, there's [this blog post](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/using-shared-memory-cuda-cc/) about static vs dynamic shared memory.