# Parallel dimension reduction (3D to 2D with sum) using Cuda

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

In a CUDA application, I have an `N x N x D` matrix that I want to reduce to `N x D` by summing over the entire first (or second) axis. How do I do this most efficiently?

Typically, N is greater than 10000 and D is 2 or 3.

A quick and naive solution using atomicAdd would be the following:

```
namespace kernel {
    __global__ void sumNND(float* devPtrIn, float* devPtrOut, const int N, const int D) {
        int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

        for (int id = index; id < N * N * D; id += stride) {
            const unsigned int d = id % D;
            const unsigned int i = (id - d) / D;
            const unsigned int n = i / N;
            const unsigned int m = i % N;

            atomicAdd(&devPtrOut[d + D * n], devPtrIn[d + D * n + N * m]);
        }
    }
}

void sumNND(const int numBlocks, const int blockSize, float* devPtrIn, float* devPtrOut, const int N, const int D) {
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemset(devPtrOut, 0, N * D * sizeof(float)));
    kernel::sumNND<<<numBlocks, blockSize>>>(devPtrIn, devPtrOut, N, D);
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
}
```

where `sumNND` is being called with

`loopSize = N * N * D`,
`blockSize = 768` and
`numBlocks = (loopSize + blockSize - 1) / blockSize`.

This is (not surprisingly) a bottleneck in my timeline, but I can't figure out how to effectively parallelize the dimension reduction. Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two optimization priorities for any CUDA programmer are:

1. Use lots of threads
2. Use memory efficiently

For your problem, you'll have no trouble with the first one - it readily decomposes into a set of problems that are independent and can be assigned to a lot of parallel threads.  The second priority is where you want to focus, then.  With respect to global memory, this means we should strive for coalesced access, whenever possible.  We should pay particular attention to the reads.

I'll need to make some assumptions.  I'll assume that your organization of dimensions is ROW, COLUMN, DEPTH and that your data is stored in the usual C-style, i.e. row-major storage.  With those assumptions, then, the request (*summing over the entire first (or second) axis*) is effectively summing over the entire row or summing over the entire column.  If you do a bit of searching here on the `cuda` tag, you'll find worked examples for both ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706599/how-to-perform-reduction-on-a-huge-2d-matrix-along-the-row-direction-using-cuda/31757588#31757588) is one such example).  Although they don't necessarily all cover the 3D case, they should provide a pretty good roadmap.  What you'll discover is that these two cases should be handled differently, with an eye towards *coalesced global memory access*, i.e. the optimization priority already mentioned.  The row-direction is also the coalescing direction, so if we need to sum rows, then we'll need to use a classical parallel reduction technique, so that we can read rows, and sum the elements together.  If we need to sum columns, the efficient kernel is much easier to write; each thread can be responsible for a column, and can just keep a running sum in a for-loop.

In your case, you appear to be summing columns (but see note below).  What follows is a worked example, comparing your approach to the faster running-column-sum method, with coalesced access (adjacent threads reading adjacent elements in memory):

```
$ cat t1263.cu
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

const int my_N = 10000;
const int my_D = 3;
const int my_blockSize = 768;
const int my_loopSize = my_N*my_N*my_D;
const int my_numBlocks = (my_loopSize + my_blockSize -1)/my_blockSize;
const int bsize = 512;
const float TOL = 0.1f;

#define HANDLE_ERROR(x) x

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define USECPSEC 1000000ULL

long long dtime_usec(unsigned long long start){

  timeval tv;
  gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
  return ((tv.tv_sec*USECPSEC)+tv.tv_usec)-start;
}

namespace kernel {
    __global__ void sumNND(float* devPtrIn, float* devPtrOut, const int N, const int D) {
        int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

        for (int id = index; id < N * N * D; id += stride) {
            const unsigned int d = id % D;
            const unsigned int i = (id - d) / D;
            const unsigned int n = i / N;
            const unsigned int m = i % N;

            atomicAdd(&devPtrOut[d + D * n], devPtrIn[d + D * n + N * m]);
        }
    }
}

void sumNND(const int numBlocks, const int blockSize, float* devPtrIn, float* devPtrOut, const int N, const int D) {
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemset(devPtrOut, 0, N * D * sizeof(float)));
    kernel::sumNND<<<numBlocks, blockSize>>>(devPtrIn, devPtrOut, N, D);
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
}

// kernel assumes 1 block assigned per row, use block-striding methodology
// assumes block size is a power of 2
__global__ void sum_rows_NND(const float * __restrict__  devPtrIn, float * __restrict__  devPtrOut, const int N, const int D) {
  __shared__ float sdata[bsize];
  sdata[threadIdx.x] = 0;
  for (int i = threadIdx.x; i < N; i += blockDim.x) // block-stride
    sdata[threadIdx.x] += devPtrIn[(blockIdx.x * N) + i];
  __syncthreads();
  for (int i = blockDim.x>>1; i > 0; i>>=1){
    if (threadIdx.x < i) sdata[threadIdx.x] += sdata[threadIdx.x+i];
    __syncthreads();}
  if (!threadIdx.x) devPtrOut[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
}



// kernel assumes one thread assigned per column sum
// launch N threads
 __global__ void sum_cols_NND(const float * __restrict__  devPtrIn, float * __restrict__  devPtrOut, const int N, const int D) {
  int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  int ido = idx;
  if (idx < N){
    for (int j = 0; j < D; j++){
      float temp = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) temp += devPtrIn[idx + (i*N)];
      devPtrOut[ido] = temp;
      ido += N;
      idx += N*N;}}
}

int main(){

  float *h_data, *d_data, *h_res1, *h_res2, *d_res;

  h_data = new float[my_loopSize];
  cudaMalloc(&d_data, my_loopSize*sizeof(d_data[0]));
  h_res1 = new float[my_N*my_D];
  h_res2 = new float[my_N*my_D];
  cudaMalloc(&d_res, my_N*my_D*sizeof(d_res[0]));
  for (int i = 0; i < my_loopSize; i++) h_data[i] = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
  cudaCheckErrors("CUDA failure");
  cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data, my_loopSize*sizeof(d_data[0]), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  // test original approach
  cudaMemset(d_res, 0, my_N*my_D*sizeof(d_res[0]));
  unsigned long long dt1 = dtime_usec(0);
  kernel::sumNND<<<my_numBlocks, my_blockSize>>>(d_data, d_res, my_N, my_D);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  dt1 = dtime_usec(dt1);
  cudaMemcpy(h_res1, d_res, my_N*my_D*sizeof(d_res[0]), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  //test columnwise reduction
  unsigned long long dt2 = dtime_usec(0);
  //sum_rows_NND<<<my_N*my_D, bsize>>>(d_data, d_res, my_N, my_D);
  sum_cols_NND<<<(my_N + bsize -1)/bsize, bsize>>>(d_data, d_res, my_N, my_D);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  dt2 = dtime_usec(dt2);
  cudaMemcpy(h_res2, d_res, my_N*my_D*sizeof(d_res[0]), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  // validate results
  for (int i = 0; i < my_N; i++)
    if (fabsf(h_res1[i] - h_res2[i]) > TOL) {printf("mismatch at %d, was %f, should be %f\n", i, h_res2[i], h_res1[i]); return -1;}
  cudaCheckErrors("program error");

  printf("results match,  kernel 1 time: %fs, kernel 2 time: %fs\n", dt1/(float)USECPSEC, dt2/(float)USECPSEC);
  // time row reduction kernel
  unsigned long long dt3 = dtime_usec(0);
  sum_rows_NND<<<my_N*my_D, bsize>>>(d_data, d_res, my_N, my_D);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  dt3 = dtime_usec(dt3);
  printf("row reduction kernel time: %fs\n", dt3/(float)USECPSEC);
  cudaCheckErrors("program error");
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_52 -o t1263 t1263.cu
$ ./t1263
results match,  kernel 1 time: 0.459971s, kernel 2 time: 0.013678s
row reduction kernel time: 0.013724s
$
```

Notes:

1. The optimized kernel is around 30x faster than your naive atomics kernel.  I suspect that a big chunk of this is not actually the use of atomics, but the uncoalesced access.  global atomics on newer GPUs can be pretty fast.
2. The first "page" (NxN) of elements column sum match between my kernel and your kernel (i.e. the first N results match).  After the first page (first N results), our results differ.  I'm pretty sure my indexing is correct, but after spending a while trying to unravel your indexing, I gave up.  I suspect you have a bug in your kernel indexing, if you are trying to sum columns, and all the aforementioned assumptions are true.
3. I also included a timing measurement of the row-summing kernel, which looks quite different, but produces almost the same timing.  This is to be expected, since optimal kernels for these types of problems will be limited by memory bandwidth, which is the same in both cases.  Optimal kernels will load all the data, once, in a coalesced fashion.  After that, the row-sum vs. column-sum mechanics have relatively little effect on the kernel time.
4. With a small modification to the initialization of the data, I think it's fairly easy to prove that your kernel is not creating the correct indexing and therefore not producing the correct row-sums after the first "page" (i.e. after the first `N` results).  After a little more study of your indexing, I have some idea of what is going wrong.  One example problem is that for `N` not divisible by `D`, your kernel `d` variable will not reset to zero after the first "page", but this is not the only issue.

Pursuant to item 4, here's a version of the code that has modified data initialization, and a full test of all `N`*`D` results.  The data initialization is such that the first column of the first page will be all zero, the next column all 1, the next column all 2, etc.  On the second page, we increment everything by 1, so the first column will be all 1, the second column will be all 2, etc.  Therefore it should be easy to agree on what the column sums should be.  For the first page, the column sums should be 0, 10000, 20000, etc.  For the second page they should be 10000, 20000, 30000, etc.  On the first column of the second page, my code produces 10000, your code produces 1.  With your changed indexing in the comments, I produce 0 for the first column of the first page, and your code produces 9999.  1 and 9999 cannot possibly be valid column sums according to the data initialization I described:

```
$ cat t1263.cu
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

const int my_N = 10000;
const int my_D = 3;
const int my_blockSize = 768;
const int my_loopSize = my_N*my_N*my_D;
const int my_numBlocks = (my_loopSize + my_blockSize -1)/my_blockSize;
const int bsize = 512;
const float TOL = 0.1f;

#define HANDLE_ERROR(x) x

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define USECPSEC 1000000ULL

long long dtime_usec(unsigned long long start){

  timeval tv;
  gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
  return ((tv.tv_sec*USECPSEC)+tv.tv_usec)-start;
}

namespace kernel {
    __global__ void sumNND(float* devPtrIn, float* devPtrOut, const int N, const int D) {
        int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

        for (int id = index; id < N * N * D; id += stride) {
            const unsigned int d = id % D;       // 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2
            const unsigned int i = (id - d) / D; // 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2
            const unsigned int n = i / N;        // 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
            const unsigned int m = i % N;        // 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2

            atomicAdd(&devPtrOut[d + D * n],    //  0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2
              devPtrIn[d + D * n + N * m]);     //  0 1 2 0+N 1+N 2+N 0+2N 1+2N 2+2N
        }
    }
}

void sumNND(const int numBlocks, const int blockSize, float* devPtrIn, float* devPtrOut, const int N, const int D) {
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemset(devPtrOut, 0, N * D * sizeof(float)));
    kernel::sumNND<<<numBlocks, blockSize>>>(devPtrIn, devPtrOut, N, D);
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
}

// kernel assumes 1 block assigned per row, use block-striding methodology
// assumes block size is a power of 2
__global__ void sum_rows_NND(const float * __restrict__  devPtrIn, float * __restrict__  devPtrOut, const int N, const int D) {
  __shared__ float sdata[bsize];
  sdata[threadIdx.x] = 0;
  for (int i = threadIdx.x; i < N; i += blockDim.x) // block-stride
    sdata[threadIdx.x] += devPtrIn[(blockIdx.x * N) + i];
  __syncthreads();
  for (int i = blockDim.x>>1; i > 0; i>>=1){
    if (threadIdx.x < i) sdata[threadIdx.x] += sdata[threadIdx.x+i];
    __syncthreads();}
  if (!threadIdx.x) devPtrOut[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
}



// kernel assumes one thread assigned per column sum
// launch N threads
 __global__ void sum_cols_NND(const float * __restrict__  devPtrIn, float * __restrict__  devPtrOut, const int N, const int D) {
  int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  int ido = idx;
  if (idx < N){
    for (int j = 0; j < D; j++){
      float temp = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) temp += devPtrIn[idx + (i*N)];
      devPtrOut[ido] = temp;
      ido += N;
      idx += N*N;}}
}

int main(){

  float *h_data, *d_data, *h_res1, *h_res2, *d_res;

  h_data = new float[my_loopSize];
  cudaMalloc(&d_data, my_loopSize*sizeof(d_data[0]));
  h_res1 = new float[my_N*my_D];
  h_res2 = new float[my_N*my_D];
  cudaMalloc(&d_res, my_N*my_D*sizeof(d_res[0]));
  for (int i = 0; i < my_loopSize; i++) h_data[i] = i%my_N + i/(my_N*my_N); //rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
  cudaCheckErrors("CUDA failure");
  cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data, my_loopSize*sizeof(d_data[0]), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  // test original approach
  cudaMemset(d_res, 0, my_N*my_D*sizeof(d_res[0]));
  unsigned long long dt1 = dtime_usec(0);
  kernel::sumNND<<<my_numBlocks, my_blockSize>>>(d_data, d_res, my_N, my_D);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  dt1 = dtime_usec(dt1);
  cudaMemcpy(h_res1, d_res, my_N*my_D*sizeof(d_res[0]), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  //test columnwise reduction
  unsigned long long dt2 = dtime_usec(0);
  //sum_rows_NND<<<my_N*my_D, bsize>>>(d_data, d_res, my_N, my_D);
  sum_cols_NND<<<(my_N + bsize -1)/bsize, bsize>>>(d_data, d_res, my_N, my_D);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  dt2 = dtime_usec(dt2);
  cudaMemcpy(h_res2, d_res, my_N*my_D*sizeof(d_res[0]), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  // validate results
  for (int i = 0; i < my_N*my_D; i++)
    if (fabsf(h_res1[i] - h_res2[i]) > TOL) {printf("mismatch at %d, was %f, should be %f\n", i, h_res2[i], h_res1[i]); return -1;}
  cudaCheckErrors("program error");

  printf("results match,  kernel 1 time: %fs, kernel 2 time: %fs\n", dt1/(float)USECPSEC, dt2/(float)USECPSEC);
  // time row reduction kernel
  unsigned long long dt3 = dtime_usec(0);
  sum_rows_NND<<<my_N*my_D, bsize>>>(d_data, d_res, my_N, my_D);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  dt3 = dtime_usec(dt3);
  printf("row reduction kernel time: %fs\n", dt3/(float)USECPSEC);
  cudaCheckErrors("program error");
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_52 -o t1263 t1263.cu
$ ./t1263
mismatch at 10000, was 10000.000000, should be 1.000000
$
```

Comment: Hi Robert. Thank you for the response. Regarding your note 4, I found an error in my indexing `(d + D * n + N * m)` should be `(d + D * n + (N * D) * m)`. But other than that, I don't see the error you're mentioning?

Comment: No, that makes your indexing broken on the first page as well.  I've added some additional text and a  modified code sample which makes it easy to decide if the results produced by your code or my code should be correct.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on which order your matrix is stored in and which dimension you want to reduce along.

For the moment, I'll ignore the *D* dimension as the operation can be thought of as reducing a matrix containing `NxN` entries where every entry contains multiple floats.

If your matrix is stored in *row-major* order and you want to reduce each row to its sum (or *column-major* and column reduction), the answer is simple:

```
const int row = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
if (row < N) { // necessary if N is not divisible by the thread block size
    float sum = 0; // stores the partial sum in a register
    for (int col = 0; col < N; ++col) {
        sum += devPtrIn[col + N * row];
    }
    devPtrOut[row] = sum; // no atomic operation necessary
}
```

This way, every thread reads memory in a coalescent fashion (see [NVIDIA's parallel forall blog](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/how-access-global-memory-efficiently-cuda-c-kernels/) for a discussion of global memory access patterns) and needs no shared or global memory writes except for the final result.

If you want to reduce along a minor dimension - let's say column reduction on a row-major matrix - the answer becomes a bit more difficult: Because of the large stride, memory access would more or less behaves like random access if we used only one entry of the column at a time.

Thus it makes sense for every thread to reduce a small number of columns along the matrix in parallel and store the partial results in shared memory:

```
constexpr int numCols = ...;
__shared__ float partial[numCols * blockDim.x];
const int threadId = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
const int begin_col = threadId * numCols;
const int end_col = min(N, (threadId + 1) * numCols);
// initialize partial to 0
...
for (int row = 0; row < N; ++row) {
    for (int col = begin_col; col < end_col; ++col) {
        partial[threadIdx.x * numCols + col] += devPtrIn[col + N * row];
    }
}
// store partial to global memory
...
```

Depending on the number of registers per thread your GPU has, it might also be possible to store the partial sums in registers by unrolling the inner loop and using local variables instead of an array, since [arrays are usually not stored in registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297067/in-a-cuda-kernel-how-do-i-store-an-array-in-local-thread-memory)

This way, we always read contiguous blocks of `numCols` floats from memory, which gives a much larger bandwidth than access with large strides.

You'll probably have to experiment with an optimal value for `numCols`, but it should be large enough that at least the memory width of the GPU memory is used to load such a block, and at the same time small enough that all shared memory for a single thread block fits onto the GPU (again see [parallel forall](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/using-shared-memory-cuda-cc/) for details)